# How to get a TypedDict corresponding to a function signature?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typing

Say I've got a function signature like this:

```
def any_foo(
    bar: Bar,
    with_baz: Optional[Baz] = None,
    with_datetime: Optional[datetime] = None,
    effective: Optional[bool] = False,
) -> Foo
```

I could of course just copy its declaration and fiddle with it enough to create the following `TypedDict`:

```
AnyFooParameters = TypedDict(
    "AnyFooParameters",
    {
        bar: Bar,
        with_baz: Optional[Baz],
        with_datetime: Optional[datetime],
        effective: Optional[bool]
    }
)
```

But this seems like such a straight-forward transformation that I wonder whether there's some easy way to create this `TypedDict` (or at least the `name: type` pairs) straight from the function.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with typing, but maybe try `any_foo.__annotations__`

Comment: I want this too. Would've been great for typehinting wrapper functions with kwargs. Python typehinting feels really limited after using Typescript a while :D

Comment: [PEP 692](https://peps.python.org/pep-0692/) is about something similar to this, but it hasn't been accepted yet.

Comment: [ParamSpec](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/) almost looks like it's going to be useful, but it isn't in this case.

Comment: @blueteeth Looks like PEP 692 was accepted, demo here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76466821/5319267.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `any_foo.__annotations__` is exactly what you want. For example:

```
from typing import Optional
def any_foo(
    req_int: int,
    opt_float: Optional[float] = None,
    opt_str: Optional[str] = None,
    opt_bool: Optional[bool] = False,
) -> int:
    pass
```

And with `any_foo.__annotations__`, you can get this:

```
{'req_int': int,
 'opt_float': typing.Optional[float],
 'opt_str': typing.Optional[str],
 'opt_bool': typing.Optional[bool],
 'return': int}
```

Note you can access to the type of return value by the `return` key.

BTW, since `return` is a reserved keyword, you cannot name an argument as `return` so there's no need to warry about a duplicate key :)

Comment: The `__annotation__` dunder property is good to know about, but does not provide what is asked. AFAIC you can't use the `__annotation__` to create a meaningful type the typehint system and IDEs understand.

As @mario-ishac commented on the question, https://peps.python.org/pep-0692/ (which has now been accepted for 3.12), can get you close but not quite (Ie.: you can write your functions such that you can interact with the typesignatures, but you need to do some work)