# Generate TypedDict from function's keyword arguments

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

`foo.py`:

```py
kwargs = {"a": 1, "b": "c"}

def consume(*, a: int, b: str) -> None:
    pass

consume(**kwargs)
```

`mypy foo.py`:

```
error: Argument 1 to "consume" has incompatible type "**Dict[str, object]"; expected "int"
error: Argument 1 to "consume" has incompatible type "**Dict[str, object]"; expected "str"
```

This is because `object` is a supertype of `int` and `str`, and is therefore inferred. If I declare:

```
from typing import TypedDict

class KWArgs(TypedDict):
    a: int
    b: str
```

and then annotate `kwargs` as `KWArgs`, the `mypy` check passes. This achieves type safety, but requires me to duplicate the keyword argument names and types for `consume` in `KWArgs`. Is there a way to generate this `TypedDict` from the function signature at type checking time, such that I can minimize the duplication in maintenance?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63893783/96588)

Comment: I'm commenting here to see if ther has been any update on this in the latest versions of mypy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be available in Python 3.12 via [PEP 692](https://peps.python.org/pep-0692/):

```py
from typing import TypedDict, Unpack, Required, NotRequired

class KWArgs(TypedDict):
    a: Required[int]
    b: NotRequired[str]

def consume(**kwargs: Unpack[KWArgs]) -> None:
    a = kwargs["a"]
    b = kwargs.get("b", ...)

consume()              # Not allowed.
consume(a=1)           # Allowed.
consume(a=1, b="abc")  # Allowed.
```

Answer (score 4):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no direct workaround on this <sup>[1]</sup>, but there is another elegant way to achieve exactly that:

We can utilize the `typing`s `NamedTuple` to create an object that holds the parameter:

```
ConsumeContext = NamedTuple('ConsumeContext', [('a', int), ('b', str)])
```

Now we define the `consume` method to accept it as a parameter:

```
def consume(*, consume_context : ConsumeContext) -> None:
    print(f'a : {consume_context.a} , b : {consume_context.b}')
```

The whole code would be:

```
from typing import NamedTuple

ConsumeContext = NamedTuple('ConsumeContext', [('a', int), ('b', str)])

def consume(*, consume_context : ConsumeContext) -> None:
    print(f'a : {consume_context.a} , b : {consume_context.b}')

ctx = ConsumeContext(a=1, b='sabich')

consume(consume_context=ctx)
```

And running mypy would yield:

```
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

It will recognize that `a` and `b` are parameters, and approve that.

And running the code would output:

```
a : 1 , b : sabich
```

However, if we change `b` to be not a string, mypy will complain:

```
foo.py:9: error: Argument "b" to "ConsumeContext" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

By this, we achieve type checking for a method by defining once it's parameters and types.

<sup>[1] Because if either defining `TypedDict` or function signature, based on the other, would require to know the other's `__annotations__`, which is not known on check-time, and defining a decorator to cast types on run-time misses the point of type checking.</sup>

Comment: Great solution. In some cases the function is defined in a third-party library, and I wouldn't be able to make the function's parameter `ConsumeContext` given that I can't change the source. But this works great for my own defined functions. I'll leave bounty up for few more days for the 1% chance this can be done from a function signature at check time without having to fetch `__annotations__`, but otherwise I'll accept and give bounty.

Comment: I don't love this solution because it makes the method signature less readable and the usage more opaque. It is committing one sin (making code less readable) to prevent another--arguably less serious--sin (duplicating code); I don't know if that is a worthy tradeoff.