# MyPy type hints for a function defined with named parameters but can take **kwargs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

Apologies for the mess of a title:

Suppose I have a function defined that takes a number of parameters.

Now later in my code, I use a dictionary to pass into `test()` all the keyword args.

```py
import argparse
from typing import Dict, Callable

def test(a: str, b: Dict[str, str], c: str, d: argparse.Namespace, e: Callable) -> None:
    if d.t:
        print(f"{a} to the {b['foo']} to the {c}!")
    else:
        print(f"{a} to the {b['foo']} to the {c} also, {e()}")

def hello() -> str:
    return "Hello"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-t", action="store_true", default=False)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    b = {'foo': 'bar'}
    info = {'b': b, "c": "foobar", "d": args, "e": hello}
    test("foo", **info)
```

When I run MyPy on my code, I get the following errors:

```
test.py:21: error: Argument 2 to "test" has incompatible type "**Dict[str, object]"; expected "Dict[str, str]"
test.py:21: error: Argument 2 to "test" has incompatible type "**Dict[str, object]"; expected "str"
test.py:21: error: Argument 2 to "test" has incompatible type "**Dict[str, object]"; expected "Namespace"
test.py:21: error: Argument 2 to "test" has incompatible type "**Dict[str, object]"; expected "Callable[..., Any]"
Found 4 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Why am I getting this? And how can I properly type hint the function to allow this?

Comment: Are you running `mypy` with any additional options?

Comment: No, my mypy config file is empty. and I'm just running `mypy script.py` from the command line.

Comment: Running this: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=52b7c02552cccf4798ebde12414e4cc0 shows no type errors, but I might have miswrote your example.

Comment: @MarioIshac I've updated my question with a reproducible example that closely resemebles my problem. My bad for thinking the problem would be the same without actually checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the [example you had before](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=52b7c02552cccf4798ebde12414e4cc0) type checks is because all values of the `plot_info` are `str` (homogeneous), and all keyword arguments being passed into the function are also `str`. There is no possibility for type mismatch, so `mypy` reports success.

In your new example, the heterogeneous types of `info` cannot be encoded into its type individually. Let's see what happens when we run [`reveal_type`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44625422/how-to-use-reveal-type-in-mypy)`(info)`:

```
note: Revealed type is 'builtins.dict[builtins.str*, builtins.object*]'
```

So we see that `mypy` has to choose a homogeneous type for the value, and it goes with `object`. Can `mypy` guarantee that a dictionary of objects satisfies your individual type constraints for `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, given that your passing `object`s under its eyes? Nope, so it errors.

To preserve the granular types of `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, we can use [`TypedDict`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/), which was made to support heterogeneously-typed values in `Dict`s:

```
class Info(TypedDict):
    b: Dict[str, str]
    c: str
    d: argparse.Namespace
    e: Callable
```

and change the `info` declaration to:

```
info: Info = {'b': b, "c": "foobar", "d": args, "e": hello}
```

This causes `mypy` to report success.

We have to duplicate the argument names and types. Sadly, [Generate TypedDict from function's keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63910610/generate-typeddict-from-functions-keyword-arguments) shows no direct workaround for this.